# Phonegap : While dragging the screen is clearing in Android Jelly bean

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am doing an App in Phonegap application for Android. I just run the application in Android Jelly bean.

I am facing issue that the screen is clearing. When I drag the a screen and without releasing the finger from the screen at that time the screen is automatically clear. After I release my finger from the screen, then the screen comes OK. The issue only seen in Jelly Bean, all other version of android its OK.

Comment: You can check for issues with phonegap build here: https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/ Google: github.com phonegap-build issues

Comment: What framework is being used? When exactly does it occur?